# Show that this ODE with boundary conditions has a unique solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

We have the ODE $$-\ddot{x}+q(t)x=g(t),\quad x(a)=x_a,\, x(b)=x_b$$
with $g\in C([a,b],\mathbb{R}$ and $q\in C([a,b],\mathbb{R}_0^+)$. Show that there is a unique solution.

---

First of all, I transformed this problem in the form
$$\dot{X}(t)=U(t)X(t)+b(t),
$$
where $X=(x,\dot{x})^T$, $U(t)=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ q(t) & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $b=-(0, g(t))^T$. Also we can write the boundary condition as
$$AX(a)+BX(b)=r(X(a),X(b)),\quad A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 0\end{pmatrix},\, B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I know that there is a theorem that states that this problem has a unique solution if
$$E=A+BW(b,a)
$$
is invertible, where
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}W(t,a)=f_x(t,X(t))W(t,a)=U(t)W(t,a).
$$
How would I show that? Or is there some other way to show it?

EDIT: Forgot the "x" in the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative argument to show that the solution of the boundary value problem is unique.  Let $\ x_1\  $ and $\ x_2\ $ be solutions and let $\ z=x_2-x_1\ $. Then $\ z\ $must satisfy the homogeneous differential equation
$$
\ddot{z}=q(t)z\ ,
$$
and the boundary conditions
$$
z(a)=z(b)=0\ .
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2z^2}{dt^2}&=2\big(z\ddot{z}+\dot{z}^2\big)\\
&\ge2q(t)z^2\\
&\ge0\ .
\end{align}
It follows that $\ \frac{dz^2}{dt}\ $ is nondecreasing, and since $\ \frac{dz^2}{dt}(a)=$$z(a)\dot{z}(a)=0\ $, it also follows also that $\ \frac{dz^2}{dt}\ge0\ $ for $\ t\ge a\ $, and hence that $\ z^2\ $ is nondecreasing for $\ t\ge a\ $.  Thus
$$
0=z(a)^2\le z(t)^2\le z(b)^2=0\,
$$
and hence $\ z(t)^2=0\ $, for $\ a\le t\le b\ $. That is , $\ x_1(t)=x_2(t)\ $, and the solution must be unique.

#### Existence of solutions

First replace the transformed version of the differential equation with an equivalent *homogeneous* version:
$$
\dot{Z}(t)=M(t)Z(t)\ ,
$$
where $\ Z=\big(x,\dot{x},v\big)^T\ $ and
$$
M(t)=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\q(t)&0&-g(t)\\0&0&0}\ .
$$
The third entry, $\ v\ $, of $\ Z\ $ must be constant, and if we impose the initial condition $\ v(a)=1\ $, then it must be identically $1$, and the second row of the differential equation becomes $\ \ddot{x}=q(t)x-g(t)v=q(t)x-g(t)\ $.

The differential equations $\ \dot{Z}(t)=M(t)Z(t)\ $ and $\ \dot{X}(t)=U(t)X(t)\ $ are then special cases of the equations
$$
\hspace{-1em}\text{(L)}\hspace{5em}x_i^\prime=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}(t)x_j\hspace{2em}(i=1,\dots,n)
$$
appearing on p.19 of Coddington and Levinson's [*Theory of Ordinary Differential Equations*](https://archive.org/details/theoryofordinary00codd/mode/2up) ($1955$ edition) for which the following theorem appears on p.20:

> **Theorem 5.1.** *For the linear system* (L), *where the functions* $\ a_{ij}\in C\ $ on $\ [a,b]\ $, *there exists one and only one solution* $ \varphi\ $ *of* (L) *on* $\ [a,b]\ $ passing through any point $\ (\tau,\xi)\in D\ $ $\big[$here, $\ D=[a,b]\times\mathbb{R}^n\ \big]$, that is, $\ \varphi(\tau)=\xi\ $.

Applying this theorem to the differential equation $\ \dot{Z}(t)=M(t)Z(t)\ $ with initial condition
$$
Z(a)=\pmatrix{0\\x_a\\1}
$$
tells us that it has a solution
$$
Z(t)=\pmatrix{\dot{x_0}(t)\\x_0(t)\\1}\ ,
$$
which must satisfy the equations $\ \ddot{x_0}=q(t)x_0-g(t)\ $, $\ x_0(a)=x_a\ $ and $\ \dot{x}_0(a)=0\ $.  This is just exactly the same $\ x_0\ $ that Lutz Lehmann defines in his answer, which the above theorem tells us must exist, and is unique.

Now applying the theorem to the differential equation $\ \dot{X}(t)=U(t)X(t)\ $ with initial condition
$$
X(a)=\pmatrix{1\\0}
$$
tells us that it has a solution
$$
X(t)=\pmatrix{\dot{y}(t)\\y(t)}\ ,
$$
which must satisfy the equations $\ \ddot{y}=q(t)y\ $, $\ y(a)=0\ $ and $\ \dot{y}(a)=1\ $. Again, this is exactly the same $\ y\ $ that Lutz Lehmann defines in his answer, which the theorem again tells us must exist, and is unique.  Exactly the same argument used above to show that $ z^2\ $ is nondecreasing shows also that $\ y^2\ $ must be non decreasing, and since $\ y(a)=0\ $, $\ \dot{y}=1\ $, there must exist $\ \epsilon\in(a,b)\ $ such that $\ y(\epsilon)>0\ $.  Therefore $\ y(b)^2\ge y(\epsilon)^2>0\ $.  So if we now define
$$
x(t)= x_0(t)+\left(\frac{x_b-x_0(b)}{y(b)}\right)y(t)
$$
just as Lutz Lehmann does in his answer, then $\ x\ $ will satisfy the differential equation
$$
\ddot{x}=q(t)x-g(t)\ ,
$$
and the boundary conditions $\ x(a)=x_a\ $, $\ x(b)=x_b\ $.

Comment: why is the solution unique?

Comment: If $\ \dot{x}(t)=f(t)\ $ and $\ f\ $ is integrable, then, by the second [FTOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part),  $\ x(t)=x(a)+\int_a^t f(u)du\ $. Thus, if $\ x(a)\ $ is specified, $\ x\ $ is uniquely determined. Although  $\ \dot{x}(a)\ $ is not specified in the statement of the problem, it must satisfy the second equation in my answer (by FTOC$2)$, and hence be given by the third, because $\ x(b)\ $ *is* specified.

Comment: I just noticed that I messed up big time. I forgot the $x$ in the equation. (see edit)Do you still know how to solve it? I'm terribly sorry.

Comment: Had I read your transformed version of the problem more carefully I should have picked up the existence of the typo in your original statement of the problem.   [Lutz Lehmann's nice answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4004452/show-that-this-ode-with-boundary-conditions-has-a-unique-solution/4005768#4005768) shows that your problem has a unique solution.  However, the succinctness of the argument might make it difficult for someone relatively inexperienced with differential equations to follow.  Are you now happy with his answer, or do you still need further explanation?

Comment: I thought about it for some time, but I need further explanation.

Comment: That helped a lot. I still don't understand why there has to be a solution though.

Comment: Do you know how to prove that the *initial value problem*
\begin{align}
\dot{X}(t)&=U(t)X(t) + b(t)\\
X(a)&=\pmatrix{x_{1a}\\x_{2a}}
\end{align}
for your transformed version of the problem has a solution (by using either the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard–Lindelöf_theorem) or any other method?

Comment: Right, by the Picard iteration. As I said, I know that there is a theorem that would solve the problem, but I have to show that the matrix $E$ is invertible. This is kind of the same idea as the Picard iteration but it used the matrix $W$ which I defined above. I find it really difficult to do calculation with $W$. Or do you see another way here?

Comment: You don't need to use $\ W\ $ to prove the existence of solutions to the *initial value* problem, and once you know that solutions to the *initial value* problem exist you can use the two which Lutz Lehmann defines in his answer to construct a solution to the *boundary value* problem.  I have now added the details to my answer.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you a lot. May I ask a few more things? From the theorem, you statet, you never used the assertion that the solution may pass through any point in $D$, right? So one can get that result pretty much from Picard-Lindelöf. Moreover, this solution is unique on $[a,b]$. Is it globally unique?

Comment: Yes, the proof of the Coddington and Levinson's theorem 5.1 is just a vanilla application of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, although I certainly *did* use the condition that a solution may pass through any point in $\ D\ $.    I did so in the first initial value problem when I specified that its solution must pass through the point $\ \big(a, \big(0,x_a,1\big)^T\big)\ $, and in the second when I specified that its solution must pass through the point  $\ \big(a, \big(1,0\big)^T\big)\ $.

Comment: In your statement of the problem you only have $q$ and $g$ defined on $[a,b]$.  To say anything about solutions outside that interval you'd need to know how $q$ and $g$ behave outside it.  If they're globally continuous, then, yes, solutions of *initial value* problems will be globally unique.  Note, however, that for the *boundary value* problem, the proof of both the existence and uniqueness  of the solution relied on the fact that $q(t)\ge0$ for $t\in[a,b]$.  Without that condition, there may either be no solution, or an infinite number of them, as Lutz Lehmann's answer shows

Answer (score 1):

You already saw that you can apply linear algebra to the related initial value problem. If $x_0$ is the solution to the ODE with IC $x_0(a)=x_a$ and $\dot x_0(a)=0$, and $y$ the solution to the homogeneous equation $-\ddot y+qy=0$ with IC $y(a)=0$, $\dot y(a)=1$, then $x=x_0+v_ay$ is a solution of the first ODE with $x(a)=x_a$ and $\dot x_a=v_a$.

Now the question can be answered when the second boundary condition can be satisfied.

1. If $y(b)\ne 0$, then $x_b=x(b)=x_0(b)+v_ay(b)$ can be solved for $v_a$.
2. If $y(b)= 0$, and accidentally $x_0(b)=x_b$, then any initial speed will land at the second boundary condition.

In the remaining case there are no solutions. Up to here this is true for any second order linear DE. Now if $y(a)=y(b)=0$ for this specific case, and as $\dot y(a)=1$, there has to be a maximum $y(c)>0$ inside the interval. But then $0>\ddot y(c)=q(c)y(c)>0$, which is impossible.

Comment: How does this answer the question? Where do you show that there is a solution and that it is unique?

Comment: The first part shows that in general there is no easy decisive answer. The second part shows that this specific situation falls in situation 1. where there is always exactly one solution.